# Change UIButton color for duration of AVAudioPlayer sound play

Tags: swift, xcode, colors, uibutton, avaudioplayer

I am trying to change the color of a UIButton when pressed. The button triggers AVAudioPlayer and I am trying to get the button color to remain changed until the sound is done playing and then revert back to original color. The code I have changes the button color once pressed and remains at the changed color after the sound is done, but doesn't change back when the player is not playing.

```
    @IBAction func soundPlay(_ sender: UIButton) {

        soundPlayer?.play()

        if (soundPlayer!.isPlaying == true) {

            playButton.backgroundColor = orangeColorLight
        }
        else {
            playButton.backgroundColor = orangeColor
        }
    }
```

Per a recommendation in the comments, I've attempted to implement an audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying delegate without success. There is little documentation on how to properly implement this unfortunately so it was pretty much guess work.

```
    @IBAction func soundPlay(_ sender: UIButton) {

        playButton.backgroundColor = orangeColorLight

        soundPlayer?.play()

        func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer,
                                         successfully flag: Bool){

            playButton.backgroundColor = orangeColor
        }
    }
```

My logic above was to set the lighter color upon button press > play sound > use audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying to watch for sound to finish playing > change color back.

Answer (score 1):

When you say `play`, you *know* the sound player is playing, so there is no point following up with a condition; just change the play button color.

Your code is now *over*. It isn't just going to sit there watching while we wait for the sound to end. There is no such thing as waiting in iOS code. (Well, there sort of is, in extreme cases, but never mind that now.) What you need is to be *called back* by the sound player when the sound ends.

Well, you can do that! Set yourself as the player's *delegate* and implement this delegate method:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudioplayerdelegate/1389160-audioplayerdidfinishplaying

It will be called when the sound ends, and now you can set the color back again in response.

---

<sub>What I have just shown you is the key concept you need to understand in iOS programming. Your code is *event-driven*. It doesn't stop and wait for things; instead, you need to *arrange to hear* whenever something happens that interests you. Cocoa provides events to tell you about all sorts of things; your job is put the right code in the right place with the right name so that your code *is* called when something of interest happens.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the reply and advice. What you've said makes perfect sense and was kind of my train of thought. Through the trial and error period I did make an attempt to implement the audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying with no luck. Lemme see if I can replicate what I did, then I repost here with updated code. Thanks!

Comment: You can't put a func inside a func like that. Well, you can, but it won't be seen by Cocoa. You need to put the delegate method where Cocoa can call it.

Comment: sorry I'm just so new to this. And I've looked for examples on online and it just crickets when it comes to implementing audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying in a any fashion. Can you please give me a hint as to where it needs to go and what code might need to go within it?

Comment: Well I'm not going to write your code for you. I don't know what you mean by "it just crickets". There are _lots_ of examples of this. Here's some code of mine that uses the delegate method. https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/21ab6f11d39913440a7fee02cca7b170b32c9700/bk2ch16p687AVQueuePlayer/ch29p952AVQueuePlayer/Player.swift

Comment: Didn't ask you to write it for me. Thanks for the example. Examples are what I'm looking for. Ways to see how others have done something similar so that I can learn.